# C# Page Fields not populating as expected

Tags: c#, ispostback

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I am trying to call the method automatically when the page loads, however, it does not work.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        customerInformation();

    }
}

protected void ddNames_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    customerInformation();
}

private void customerInformation()
{
    string dbString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TechSupportDBConString"].ConnectionString;
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Name='" + ddNames.Text + "'";

    SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(dbString);
    Connection.Open();

    SqlCommand Com = new SqlCommand(query, Connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = Com.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        lblName.Text = reader["Name"].ToString() + "'s Personal Information";
        lblAddress.Text = reader["Address"].ToString() + "\n" + reader["City"].ToString() + " " + reader["State"].ToString() + " " + reader["ZipCode"].ToString();
        lblPhone.Text = reader["Phone"].ToString();
        lblEmail.Text = reader["Email"].ToString();

        reader.Close();
        Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: what exactly is the problem?`IsPostBack` means your `customerInformation` will only be called on first time page load.in subsequent postbacks this method would not be called again which is expected behaviour.However if you want to load customer info on some button click you need to explicitly call `customerInformation`

Comment: @Neel I want all the labels to be updated with the proper data from the database as the page loads for the first time. Since there will already be a value selected in the dropdown list.

Comment: The Dispose and Close logic in your method is wrong. You could be leaking Connection objects.

Comment: Dropdown selected item should be `ddNames.SelectedItem.Text` or in case of value `ddNames.SelectedValue`

Comment: Please explain what do you mean "It does not work". For example, is the customerInformation() called? or is the SqlDataReader Read() executing?? elaborate..!

Answer (score 2):

Ok looking through your code I can see the connection of reader and database is closed in loop itself which should not be done.

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();    
if (reader.HasRows)
{
     while (reader.Read())
     {
                //populate fields from reader
     }
}
else
{
     lbl.Text = "No records found.";
}
reader.Close();
Connection.Close();
```

Next thing which I noticed that dropdown selected text/value should be either `ddNames.SelectedItem.Text` or in case of value passing `ddNames.SelectedValue`.

Next thing make sure that each reader name should exactly match with table column name.

Last but not least always do a proper null check before applying `ToString()`.if any column has null value `ToString()` would fail to convert.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Strangely enough I get the "No records found." message as the page loads. But the dropdown list works perfectly fine.

Comment: So clearly reader is null..Now go and check your connection string and query.(if possible with dropdown selected value test is sql first)

Comment: On the right path but the reader and connection should be in `using() {...}` blocks. And there is no loop in the original code.